# Send strings over the network

Tags: python, sockets

Here's a simple question and I'm surprised I haven't come across a similar one already.

I would like two processes to send strings (messages) to each other with send() and receive() functions. Here's a basic example:

```py
# Process 1
# ... deal with sockets, connect to process 2 ...
msg = 'An arbitrarily long string\nMaybe with line breaks'
conn.send(msg)
msg = conn.receive()
if process1(msg):
    conn.send('ok')
else:
    conn.send('nok')
```

and

```py
# Process 2
# ... deal with sockets, connect to process 1 ...
msg = conn.receive()
conn.send(process2(msg))
msg = conn.receive()
if msg == 'ok':
    print('Success')
elif msg == 'nok':
    print('Failure')
else:
    print('Protocol error')
```

I know it is **quite** easy with bare stream sockets, but that's still cumbersome and error prone (do several conn.recv() inside a loop and check for size, like HTTP or end of stream marker, like SMTP, etc).

By the way, it doesn't necessarily need to use sockets, as long as messages of any size can be reliably carried through the network in an efficient manner.

Am I doing something wrong? Isn't there a simple library (Twisted AMP doesn't look simple) doing exactly that? I've been searching the Internet for a few hours without success :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org), there is an excellent Python binding called [pyzmq](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq).
It is a library for writing all kinds of distributed software, based on the
concept of message queues.
The project got a lot of hype lately, and you will find numerous examples and
tutorials on the web.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks! Here's the doc I think I'll use (for anyone seeing this question): https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pair.html